# Displaying base64 images from DB as string slows down the page

Tags: php, node.js

I use fs.readFileSync to convert images to string for storing in MongoDB, and for displaying them in PHP view, i use :

```
<?php
   $alt = $image_key['alt_name'];
   printf("<img src='data:image/png;base64,%s' class='img-responsive pull-
   left' alt='$alt'/>", $image_key['img']);
?>
```

It's working, but the image name is the long base64 string - which i thing slows down the loading of the page, what's the best why to do it?
Is there's a way to make the base64 string shorter?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to confirm that it is the image causing the slowness?

Comment: why did you store it as a blob to begin with and not stored in a folder instead? what's the size of those images anyway?

Comment: *"Is there's a way to make the base64 string shorter?"* - No, because that would break your image.

Comment: No, i just want to make sure the it's the right way... i noticed the delay while trying to edit it's HTML in inspect element->elements....

Comment: Fred , thanks, i'm not so enthusiastic for this method also... it's costumer's demands.... he want's all user's data to be stored in one place....

Comment: @RoyBarOn You should ping a member directly with the `@` as I did here. The other person you seem to have responded to, may not be present in the post anymore. I only saw yours because I still am. As for having all users' data stored in one place, then that gets a bit complicated depending on the amount of users and the size of those images. One thing that could slow things down is that the db isn't properly indexed and the file sizes also. There is a way to rename files as per a user's id, and then access those with a `WHERE` clause in a query, and storing the images in (a) folder(s).

Comment: @RoyBarOn addendum to my above: If the db ever gets corrupted or deleted, then what? You need to think about that. Storing a blob isn't always a good idea.

Comment: Store paths, not blobs...

Comment: @Fred-ii-thanks, i'm  fully aware of the problems, caused by saving picture and files in db . By posting the question i wanted to get the pro and cons about that issue... or just to get a professional advice about how to do these kind of stuff... so thanks again.

Comment: @MontasarJarraya thanks, i guess that's what i'll do.